# Moped: Rename mongodb collection

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid3, moped

How can one rename a collection, using Mongoid + Moped driver?

Is there a Moped implementation of http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/renameCollection/?

Comment: I would move the collection instead by copying the data, of course the better idea is not to if the collection is too big (much like changing the shard key for a large range).

Answer (score 0):

Renaming a collection is a serious change and won't work in a sharded environment.

But, you could do that via an app using (probably) the admin db and db commands. So I probably would take a look into: [the Moped Driver Docs](http://mongoid.org/en/moped/docs/driver.html#behaviour)

Comment: this doesn't actually help. the linked docs don't give a way to execute a "raw" mongo command like renameCollection

Comment: I did not tested it but when you created a session, it says: ".. you can interact with it in a similar fashion that you would with the mongo console."

Answer (score 0):

A collection can be renamed via the [Moped::Collection#rename](https://github.com/mongoid/moped/blob/master/lib/moped/collection.rb#L57) method.

Here's an example, renaming the "foo" collection to "bar":

```
Mongoid::default_session[:foo].rename("bar")
```

Under the hood, the command is constructed like so:

```
session.
  with(database: "admin", read: :primary).
  command(renameCollection: "#{database.name}.#{name}", to: "#{database.name}.#{to_name}")
```

Answer (score 0):

I just recently migrated to Mongoid 7.x and sessions no longer exist (it's now clients)

The API seems to have removed .rename() so instead you can use this:

```
client = Mongo::Database.new(Mongoid.default_client, Mongo::Database::ADMIN, Mongoid.default_client.database.options)
client.command(renameCollection: "#{source_db}.#{source_collection}", 
    to: "#{target_db}.#{target_collection}", dropTarget: true)
```